# Android OpenGL ES 2.0:How to zoom texture with depth map?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Android OpenGL ES 2.0, I bind bitmap and depth map bitmap to `fragment_shader.glsl`,

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D sDepth;
uniform sampler2D sTexture;
uniform float time;

varying vec2 varyTexCoord;

void main() {
    vec4 depth=texture2D(sDepth, varyTexCoord);    
    gl_FragColor=texture2D(sTexture, varyTexCoord);
}
```

`sTexture` : original bitmap

`sDepth`: depth map(ARGB_8888, 0~255, 0:far 255:near)

vertex_shader.glsl

```
attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec2 vTexCoord;
uniform mat4 vMatrix;

varying vec2 varyTexCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vPosition;
    varyTexCoord = vTexCoord;
}
```

now I want to make parallax effect :According to the depth of field value, zoom in the image, the zoom in of the near area is higher than that of the far area, creating parallax effect.
Can you give us some ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a mesh on a base of regular grid, let say 10x10 in (x,y) space.
2. Set z coordinate from depth map.
3. Make uv coordinates.
4. Render mesh with you color texture, and use gl_position = projectionMatrix * scale * vertex;
5. Try different dimensions for grid to find best one.